# Access svn repository on windows host from linux redhat

Tags: linux, windows, svn, ssh, remote-server

How to access a svn repository on an open windows server?  I have access from a different widows box, but now need to access from Linux box.

When I enter

```
ssh -v HOST
```

The output is

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to HOST port 22.
debug1: connect to address HOST port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to HOST port 22: Connection refused
```

When I enter

```
svn info svn+ssh:"//HOST/dir/svn_repository"
```

The output is

```
svn: 'svn+ssh://HOST/dir/parent dir' is not a working copy
svn: 'svn+ssh://HOST/dir/parent dir' does not exist
```

I also tried

```
svn info svn+ssh:"//HOST/dir/svn_repository/project"
```

The windows box uses tortoisesvn and the path is something like "file://Host/dir/svn_repository/project"

I just tried 
    svn list file:///...%20..%20.../repository/project,

and 
    svn list 'file:///... .. .../repository/project'.

Those commands give the error now is unable to open an ra_local session to URL.   I have asked sys admin and tech support, but they are not familiar with svn, ssh, or Linux to windows communications.

The server is a 2008 server running visualsvn.  I'm able to access the repo from a windows 7 machine using tortoisesvn with path 'file://server/path/repo/project'.  Here are my most recent attempts to access from fedora 6 box

```
<bash>$ svn info 'file://server/path/repo/project'
'file://server/path/repo/project':  (Not a valid URL)
svn: A problem occurred; see other errors for details

<bash>$ svn info 'file:///server/path/repo'
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///server/path/repo'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be svn+ssh://HOST rather than svn+ssh:"HOST"?

Comment: Ask SVN-admin, how to reach repo from LAN

Comment: I asked admin, they have no idea how to support ssh, or in this case, probably clear text since file:... protocol, between Linux and 2008 server.

Comment: The people that are marking this question negative, can you provide an explanation so I can improve the question.  I'm trying to switch from a windows 7 box to Linux to get more speed / memory / processors, but would like to utilize the repository that is on a windows 2008 server.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" is reason for downvotes. You didn't try to read SVN Book

Comment: I read the book, extracted the protocol / port relationship.  I also met with the svn server administrator, a network engineer, and a database engineer.  Have a meeting this morning with a different security / svn engineer.  I would hardly characterize that as no research effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the repository was created on a shared drive.  The repository is not in an svn server.  Moving the repository into a server should allow access from linux machine.

Follow on question: [visualsvn error while loading existing repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919182/visualsvn-error-while-loading-existing-repository)

Answer (score 0):

> ssh: connect to HOST port 22: Connection refused

**must** means for you "svn+ssh:// will not work, because for svn over ssh repository-host must have at least ssh enabled and it hasn't it"

Even enabled ssh-daemon doesn't provide for you `svn+ssh://` access automagically, because [it require additional actions](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html) on repository-host

`file:///`-type URL is TortoiseSVN *can* indicate, that repository-host may hot have any SVN-server at all (remote Win-box just uses the abilities of Windows Network to browse and reach remote shared drives - **BAD IDEA (tm)** for repositories over LAN, BTW)

**PS:** `protocol://"PATH/TO"` is wrong format of URL anyway. While it doesn't affect you in *this* case, it must be `protocol://PATH/TO`

Comment: I just tried file:///...%20..%20.../repository/project, and 'file:///... .. .../repository/project'.  Error now is unable to open an ra_local session to URL.

Comment: I'll try to get the admin to start an ssh daemon on windows 2008 server.

Comment: They recommended instead of ssh daemon on windows 2008 server, to try to do a file / disk share from the Linux box.

Comment: @user3969377 - shares and file:/// access is bad, stupid, ugly Windows-style of life. Easy&fast way of sharing repo (and **The Right Way**) for any platform - `svnserve` and `svn://` repositories

Comment: I don't have the option to dictate the server implementation / protocol.

Comment: @user3969377 - in this case don't cry, when (not if) your repo will be broken