# visualsvn error while loading existing repository

Tags: svn, version, visualsvn-server

On a windows 2008 server, a svn repository has been created using tortoisesvn from a remote Windows 7 machine.  We would like to load the repository into VisualSVN, ref https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/.  After setting the file location and the new repository location, and clicking the import button, there is an error similar to the following message (written from memory).

```
error: Expected fs format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'
```

What should be done to resolve this error?  I had read previous posts suggesting the issue was the svn version.  Is it possible to save the repository in an older format?  A command window was opened, but the commands svn and svnadmin were not recognized.  On the bottom right of the VisualSVN server splash window, there is a link to show the version.  The svn version was 1.6xxx.

Similar posts
http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-413
[SVN Error: Expected fs format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838392/svn-error-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-3-found-format-4)

Steps for upgrading visualsvn
https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00036/

This post is related to previous post: 
[Access svn repository on windows host from linux redhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889883/access-svn-repository-on-windows-host-from-linux-redhat)

One solution is to use svnadmin

location of svnadmin, see bottom of this link: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/

To migrate to different svn version, follow transfer repository steps: [How do I export (and then import) a Subversion repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450/how-do-i-export-and-then-import-a-subversion-repo)

Migrate from toitisesvn to apachee/svn (VisualSVN) is described here: http://www.meinbinary.com/2009/09/migrating-local-repository-created-with.html

General migration proceedure is described here, towards the bottom:  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should be done to resolve this error?

**Best and correct way:**

Use [up-to-date VisualSVN Server distro](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/), which have also SVN 1.8.* at backend (3.0.1), not ancient as mammoth's bullshit version with older, than *existing* repository, FS format (SVN 1.6 can't handle 1.8 repositories)

**Ugly and lame way**

From Win7-box (or any other box, which have SVN 1.8 client and can reach original repo), [create dump of repo and load this dump](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/#import-incompatible) into still outdated *existing* VisualSVN Server installation (svnadmin must exist on path `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnadmin`), using CLI-tools, not GUI

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.  Unfortunately, upgrading the version is not an option due to level of effort involved to dump / load existing projects and also due to the server risk management; essentially, version 1.6 functions don't modify it.  But was able to locally update svn and then use version 1.6 to load the dump.